# Using Angular async pipe and onPush change detection from 3rd party libraries

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular-changedetection

I have trying to get a grasp on Angulars async pipe and rxjs observables lately, and i find myself having to fall back to subscribing to the observable in the .ts file and calling the change detection manually, when using BehaviorSubjects from 3rd party libraries.

I am trying to build a list using a setup like this, but the BehaviorSubject returns an array from an object from a 3rd party library.

```
<app-list-item
    [innerItem]="item"
      *ngFor="let item of (3rdPartyComponent.itemBehaviorSubject | async)">
</app-list-item>
```

My question is: Is it possible to use Async pipes like this, from a module outside angular, or does change detection just not trigger? And if this is true, what can I do to bring this 3rd party library in line with angular so the Async pipe does its job?

Comment: What do you mean, by 3rd parties libraries? Do you have access to the subject or not? Can you instantiate the subject? The whole concept of the `async` pipe is that will handle the rendering automatically. You can always create a `subcription` and avoid the async pipe if you wish.

Comment: I mean  that the BehaviorSubject is instantiated, and have its "next" method called inside another module imported from NPM in package.json. My understanding is that change detection happens inside a zone.js zone. If the BehaviorSubject.next method is called outside the angular zone, won't Change Detection miss it?

Comment: Every npm package that you use, you import it an a module. Either you declare a component or pipe or you provide a service. After that everything works like your code.

Comment: I don't understand what exactly is your problem.. You see in logs that messages have data, but item is not rendered? have you tried to print in your screen your subject as json?

Comment: Yes, i have tried logging where the BehaviorSubject.next is called. Since I am trying to use the Async pipe, I can't really log in the subscriber, as that is by |async inside the ngFor loop. But the data is there and the list DOES render, just not when it is updated. It renders when something else triggers the change detection later.

Comment: But where exactly is the change detection implemented? If it is implemented in angulars zone.js, then asynchronous calls from the default zone shouldn't trigger change detection, right?

Comment: Create an `Observable` from your `BehaviorSubject`. `Subscribe` on it and `console.log` the emissions.

Comment: I just did. The observable logs the changes out as expected, when they happen. And if i inject ChangeDetectorRef and call detectChanges() then the view updates when the subject emits a new value. The question is why the async pipe doesn't trigger change detection.

Comment: No, `zone.js` is a 3rd party library that emit async events and Angular, receive this events and decides when to render. When you are in an `OnPush` component, only async pipes and the changes of the input makes the component to render. Otherwise rendering will happen after every async task or change.

Comment: When i remove onPush, rendering still doesn't happen. The only way that seems to work is using the ChangeDetectorRef, but then why on earth doesn't async detect that the data was emitted?

Comment: I am not sure, but probably, if you replace the `BehoviorSubject` with the Observable, it will work. Anyway, you can replace, the Subject with the actual value by creating an subscription. Next time, try to give a stackblitz, it would really help...

Comment: That doesn't make sense, BehaviorSubject IS an Observable.

Comment: No it is not... That's why it has an extention method called `.asObservable()`

Comment: (3rdPartyComponent.itemBehaviorSubject.asObservable() | async) doesn't improve anything

Comment: If you did `(3rdPartyComponent.itemBehaviorSubject | async)` and it worked than it is NOT BehaviorSubject, I think you need to expose more code so we can help

Comment: `(3rdPartyComponent.itemBehaviorSubject.asObservable() | async)` That was not what I suggest . I believe you should close the issue for now...

Answer (score 0):

#### The Issue

It looks to me like what you're doing should work. I've solved this same issue with async pipe in the past and not run into any issues.

#### Finding the Problem

I wrote a little utility that lets you leave/enter Angular's ngZone within an observable. You can try it out, though my experience is that you *shouldn't* need this with async pipe.

This is more useful when you're building long complex transformations and want to create (controlled) local mutation that doesn't trigger angular change detection.

This is pretty old, so you may need to tweak it? Not sure.

```ts
// Inject ngZone
constructor(private ngZone: NgZone) { }

/*****
 * Wrap every emission of an observable (next, complete, & error)
 * With a callback function, effectively removing the invocation
 * of these emissions from the observable to the callback.
 *
 * This isn't really too useful except for as a helper function for
 * our NgZone Operators where we leverage this wrapper to run an
 * observable in a specific JavaScript environment.
 *****/
callBackWrapperObservable<T>(
  input$: Observable<T>, 
  callback: (fn: (v) => void) => void
): Observable<T> {
  const callBackBind = fn => (v = undefined) => callback(() => fn(v));
  const bindOn = (ob, tag) => callBackBind(ob[tag].bind(ob));
  return new Observable<T>(observer => {
    const sub = input$.subscribe({
      next: bindOn(observer, "next"),
      error: bindOn(observer, "error"),
      complete: bindOn(observer, "complete")
    });
    return { unsubscribe: () => sub.unsubscribe() };
  });
}

ngZoneEnterObservable<T>(input$: Observable<T>): Observable<T> {
  return this.callBackWrapperObservable(input$, this.ngZone.run.bind(this.ngZone));
}
ngZoneEnter<T>(): MonoTypeOperatorFunction<T> {
  return this.ngZoneEnterObservable;
}

ngZoneLeaveObservable<T>(input$: Observable<T>): Observable<T> {
  return this.callBackWrapperObservable(input$, this.ngZone.runOutsideAngular.bind(this.ngZone));
}
ngZoneLeave<T>(): MonoTypeOperatorFunction<T> {
  return this.ngZoneLeaveObservable;
}
```

You could try it out like this:

In your `.ts`:

```ts
items$ = ngZoneEnterObservable(
  3rdPartyComponent.itemBehaviorSubject 
);
```

or

```ts
items$ = 3rdPartyComponent.itemBehaviorSubject.pipe(
  ngZoneEnter()
);
```

Then instead of `3rdPartyComponent.itemBehaviorSubject | async` you can just write `items$ | async`

You can also use the `tap` operator as a quick and dirty means to check if an observable has fired

```ts
/***
 * Curried function that logs the message (msg) and
 * value (val)
 ***/
function logMsg(msg: string) {
  return (val: any = null) => 
    msg == null || msg.length < 1 ? 
      console.log(val) :
      val == null ? 
        console.log(msg) :
        console.log(`${msg}: `, val);
}

/***
 * RxJS Pipeable Operator:
 * Optionally prepend a message before logging 
 * the current value to the console.
 ***/
function log<T>(msg = ""): MonoTypeOperatorFunction<T> {
  return pipe(tap(logMsg(msg)));
}

items$ = 3rdPartyComponent.itemBehaviorSubject.pipe(
  log("Before ngZoneEnter"),
  ngZoneEnter(),
  log("After ngZoneEnter"),
);
```